# Flag queue still shows some closed questions

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, flag-queue

I was going through the flag queue and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343695/where-can-i-download-jpcsc-dll-closed) that was closed one hour ago and still was showing up with a "very low quality" and a "too localized" flags.

I don't know if there's a lag in the elimination from the flag queue or if the flags were not cleared when the question was closed (or any other reason I'm failing to see).

If the question is marked as offensive/spam, then I understand the need of attention, but for any other case: is it possible to prevent closed questions from showing up in the queue?

(Just in case, it's not that I saw this because I had the queue open for a long time).

[image]

Comment: Gonna take a wild guess that someone flagged it after it was closed.  I agree that there should be some automatic culling here.  Low quality flags should be wiped from the queue when the question is closed, for instance.

Comment: @Won't - the questions are definately flagged *before* they have been closed, the same issue also applies to migrated questions. [Here is a dupe i posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95211/flagged-but-closed-question-not-being-removed-from-the-flagged-posts-page) before i found this question, it has another example in it which i watched from the moment it was listed on the page.

Comment: Seems that they got rid of the close button but the queue still shows closed questions. I just stumbled across one that's 22 hours old ([screenshot](http://static.ellipsix.net/ext-tmp/closedsnapshot.png)).