# Flagged (but closed) question not being removed from the Flagged Posts page

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flag queue still shows some closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95072/flag-queue-still-shows-some-closed-questions)

In the [Flagged Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged) page, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353539/who-can-analysis-the-running-result-of-this-program) has been sitting around for a few hours:

[image]

I would expect that once a post was closed for any reason then it should disappear from this page and be moved to the [Recently Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=close) page? After all, once it has been closed there is no point in keeping it there for further flagging, is there? And if there is a reason to keep it there, the `Close` button shouldn't be available for it.

Comment: Thanks @Barry, this is definitely a dupe, that other question didn't show up in the suggestions list when i typed the question up.