# Flags against answers to migrated questions

Tags: bug, flags, deleted-questions, migrated-questions, vote-to-delete

There's apparently a flag still in the queue on [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647125/implement-ssl-in-website?noredirect=1) to a question that got migrated.

[image: Already deleted]

There's at least two odd things though:

1. Despite loading the flag page well after the post was migrated I'm still being offered delete as an action on a post that clearly was deleted even before clicking the drop down arrow.
2. It doesn't even meet the rules for deletion anyway since it's currently scored at 0!

This seems similar to [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95072/flag-queue-still-shows-some-closed-questions), but applies to an answer, not a question and I suspect the actions taken on migration play a role in this.

Why didn't this deletion dismiss the flags on the answers, or at least suppress them unless the migration got rejected?

Another example:

[image: Second example]

Comment: That's a pretty good turtle you drew there in black.

Comment: Yes, oops. That second one is my fault. I flagged it from the review queue then looked at the question rather than the other way around. I then voted to close the question as off topic (not migrate), which was the 5th vote so it got migrated.

Comment: @Ben - oops, I'll remove that one then. I'm pretty sure the first one was a bug though

Comment: Isn't it still a bug? I would expect that a flag on a deleted answer should be removed...